# How to Encrypt data in ruby same as SecretKeySpec?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a string in ruby using Cipher with AES algorithm. I have example written in Java. I have taken help from this example and written code in Java but not able to get the same output as in JAVA.

Following is the code written in java

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static final String PHONENUMBER_PARAM = "phoneNumber";
    public static final String PIN_PARAM ="pin";

    public static final String MERCHANTID_PARAM = "merchantId";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String phoneNumber ="+917738995286";
    String pin ="5577";

    String merchantId ="527425858";
    String encodedKey ="vPDkdTDrcygLPROzd1829A==";

    String payLoad = PHONENUMBER_PARAM + "=" +         URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8")+ "&" + PIN_PARAM + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pin, "UTF-8") ;

    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey.getBytes());

    Key encryptionKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "AES");

    byte[] utf8Bytes = payLoad.getBytes("utf-8");

    byte[] encryptedBody = encrypt(encryptionKey, utf8Bytes);
    String encryptedData = new  String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedBody));

    System.out.println("encryptedData:" + encryptedData);
 }
private static byte[] encrypt(Key encryptionKey, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(1, encryptionKey);
    return c.doFinal(data);
}
}
```

**Output of this code is**

> encryptedData:lE40HlECbxU/mWRivF/+Szm3PprMoLW+Y7x911GczunakbG8l+A2JVEEP8gTw6xy

I tried to write the same code in ruby. Ruby Code is:

```
payLoad = "phoneNumber=%2B917738995286&pin=5577"

encodedKey = "vPDkdTDrcygLPROzd1829A=="

decodedKey = Base64.decode64(encodedKey)

dKey = decodedKey.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes128').encrypt
encryptionKey  = cipher.update(dKey) 
encryptionKey<< cipher.final


utf8Bytes = payLoad.bytes
uKey = utf8Bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join

scipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes128').encrypt
scipher.key = encryptionKey  
encryptedBody = scipher.update(uKey) 
encryptedBody<< scipher.final

encryptedData  = Base64.encode64(encryptedBody)
```

**Output of this code is**

> CqFmCKJ004PsoXi2tDCTBmx7/iTHVyDsFH9y8NWNrEP3k3bOQp7h8uyl/a7Z\nYi9ZmcXSspo6FCyCo6fJIwPohg==\n

Don't know where is the error. I have already worked for 2 days but not able to get any answer. Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure you do not post your production keys, this can be insecure (if you did - change them ASAP)

Comment: I would use `puts some_value` to debug each step and find the differences

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following version outputs the same result as your Java code:

```
# crypt.rb
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

payLoad = "phoneNumber=%2B917738995286&pin=5577"
encodedKey = "vPDkdTDrcygLPROzd1829A=="

decodedKey = Base64.decode64(encodedKey)

scipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-ecb').encrypt
scipher.key = decodedKey
encryptedBody = scipher.update(payLoad)
encryptedBody << scipher.final

encryptedData  = Base64.encode64(encryptedBody)
puts encryptedData


$ ruby crypt.rb
# => lE40HlECbxU/mWRivF/+Szm3PprMoLW+Y7x911GczunakbG8l+A2JVEEP8gT
#    w6xy
```

Notable differences from your ruby script version:

- You **must specify the cipher mode**. The problem is that Java [defaults to the ECB mode](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/57071) whereas ruby defaults to the CBC mode. By the way, the ECB mode is considered less-secure today and **you actually [should not use it](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946)**.
- In ruby, you tried to re-encrypt the Base64-decoded version of your encryption key, which is something you don't do in the Java version.
- In ruby, there is no need to do the string to byte conversions, you can encrypt strings right away.

So, although the two scripts output the same encrypted data now, I would strongly consider changing the AES mode of operation, to actually stay secure.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @BoraMa, I have accepted it and voted it up also. Its not showing may be because of less reputation point.

Comment: Aha, I thought you should be able to *accept* an answer regardless of reputation (not upvote, this is enabled since rep. 15 I think). Never mind, Yogesh, glad that it worked for you.